# why html created on the fly not registered in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When an html element is created on thy fly using jquery or javascript,event handlers are not attached to the element.
so we normally attach the events to its parent or document that is not created dynamically
then how the document delegate the event to newly created element.?
Please clear this doubt.

Comment: The [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/introduction.html) is clever, it knows when you add stuff and take it away.

Comment: Post some code please.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how delegation works and how it differs from assigning to the elements.

Suppose, for a moment, I have a a DOM with six buttons

```
<div id="button-home">
  <button value="1">Button</button>
  <button value="2">Button</button>
  <button value="3">Button</button>
  <button value="4">Button</button>
  <button value="5">Button</button>
  <button value="6">Button</button>
</div>
```

Now, there are two ways I could go about it.  I could attach a handler to each and every button:

var buttonHome = document.getElementById("button-home");
var buttons = buttonHome.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.onclick = function() {
    alet("You clicked me!");
  }
}

Now, if you add or remove buttons, you have to update your handlers.

The other option is to set up ONE handler on `button-home` that looks to see what button was pushed.

```
document.getElementById("button-home").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
 // e.target is the clicked element! 


  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName === "button") { 

    console.log("You clicked on button value: " + target.value;);
   }
 });
```

Now, in the delegated model, because there is only one click handler on the outside of the buttons, it doesn't matter how we add/change or re-arrange the buttons inside.  The click handler will figure out what we did.

Better code example and explanation here:

http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate